# php mysql connection get error message

Tags: php, mysql

this is my first php code , i am trying to connect to a database with user name = "root" and password = "root"

i have a connection file called `dbConnection.php` 
as following :

```
<?php
echo "in connection file";
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$db = "ledDB";
echo "<br> db-connection : vars definde ";


//connection to the database
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
echo "db-connection : initilize connection ";
mysql_select_db($db);
echo "db-connection : connection done";
// Check connection

echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

and i call it in a file called what.php :

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
include "dbConnection.php";
echo "ohhhh";
?>
```

this returns status code 500 which is internal server error

but i want to know what is the error to fix it how can i get the error message ?

i tried

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

but it is not returning any thing.

can any one help me please ?

Comment: Is MySql running & login credentials are verified?

Comment: make sure your server is running.

Comment: Check the username and password by run the mysql using commandline

Answer (score 0):

if you are having password on localhost then use password otherwise leave it blank

```
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","yourpassword","yourdb");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";


// make the current db
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db ( $conn , $dbname );
if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('Can\'t connect to Database : ' . mysql_error());
}


?>
```

Comment: if you can run in localhost than password="" and username ="root"

Answer (score 0):

You mysqli_connect() method.

```
<?php
echo "in connection file";
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$db = "ledDB";
echo "<br> db-connection : vars definde ";


//connection to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
echo "db-connection : initilize connection ";
mysqli_select_db($conn,$db);
echo "db-connection : connection done";
// Check connection

echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Thing is to Change your connection method to mysqli or my personal favorite PDO.
PDO Example:

```
class db extends pdo{
    //Website Variables

    public $sitedb = '';
    public $siteconfig;
    public $sitesettings = array(
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'yourdb',
        'username'  => 'youruser',
        'password'  => 'yourpass',
    );

    public function __construct(){

        $this->sitedb = new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$this->sitesettings['host']};" .
            "dbname={$this->sitesettings['database']};" .
            "charset=utf8",
            "{$this->sitesettings['username']}",
            "{$this->sitesettings['password']}"
        );

        $this->sitedb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }


}

$db = new db();
```

Then you can extend your PDO class to new classes after including the db.php page.
Example Select:

```
   class yourclass extends db {
           public function SelectUsers() {
                    global $db;
                    $query = <<<SQL
                    SELECT email
                    FROM users
                    WHERE active = :active
   SQL;
           $resource = $db->sitedb->prepare( $query );
           $resource->execute( array (
                  ':active' => 1,
                  ));
            $count = $resource->rowCount();
            foreach($resource as $user){
                    $this->email = $user['email'];
              }
          }
         }
```